# Can't install nodejs in Termux on Android

Tags: android, node.js, termux

When I do `pkg install nodejs` or `pkg install nodejs-lts`
it gives me a this message:

```
 Checking availability of current mirror: ok
Ign:1 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games InRelease
Ign:2 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science InRelease
Err:3 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release
  OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to dl.bintray.com:443
Err:4 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science Release
  OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to dl.bintray.com:443
Ign:5 https://main.termux-mirror.ml stable InRelease
Err:6 https://main.termux-mirror.ml stable Release
  Redirection from https to 'http://ww38.main.termux-mirror.ml/dists/stable/Release' is forbidden
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
E: The repository 'https://main.termux-mirror.ml stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
```

I do it a second time:
`pkg install nodejs-lts`
Output:

```
Checking availability of current mirror: ok
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Unable to locate package nodejs
```

It doesn't let me install any pkg's.

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried reinstalling Termux.
- I tried `apt update` and `apt upgrade` the Output:

```
Ign:1 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games InRelease
Ign:2 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science InRelease
Err:3 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release
  OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to dl.bintray.com:443
Err:4 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science Release
  OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to dl.bintray.com:443
Ign:5 https://main.termux-mirror.ml stable InRelease
Err:6 https://main.termux-mirror.ml stable Release
  Redirection from https to 'http://ww38.main.termux-mirror.ml/dists/stable/Release' is forbidden
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
E: The repository 'https://main.termux-mirror.ml stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
```

- I did `termux-setup-storage` when first opening the app after i reinstalled it.

### My phone details

> Phone: Xiaomi Redimi Note 10 Pro
> MIUI version: MIUI Global 12.5.7 
> Android Version: 11 RKQ1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this:
https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/6726

That repo has been down since May of 2021.
The article lists a few solutions, including setting a mirror. Just be aware of 3rd party mirrors that could be security risks.